# Android: Eliminar imagen del servidor

Tags: android

Necesito eliminar una imagen del servidor, antes lo que hacia era hacer una instancia de CheckIn que es donde tengo mis Getts y Setts despues llamaba a checkIn.getImages().remove(positionPicture); y le removia del ArrayList de Bitmasp la imagen que se econtrara en la posicion de la imagen que se quiere elimina, todoo a bien pero la imagen en el servidor aun existe, entonces como seria el proceso para eliminarla del servidor?

```
int positionPicture = intent.getIntExtra("positionPicture", 0);//en mi variable obtengo la posicion
            CheckIn checkIn = CheckIn.getInstance();//hago una instancia de checkIn
            checkIn.getImages().remove(positionPicture);//del arreglo elimino la imagen en esa posicion
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo ideal seria que te programes un script en PHP que reciba un parametro GET de confirmacion con el nombre de la imagen para que sea el PHP quien la elimine del servidor. Cuando ya tengas el script simplemente desde java hacer el request al archivo pasandole dicho parametro.